# Tips for debugging latex errors in Doxygen

Tags: latex, doxygen

Right now I get an error message saying:

```
No file _formulas.aux.
...
! Missing $ inserted.
...
```

I've tried looking for and single `@f$` tags in the code, but I have not been successful in locating the culprit thus far. How can I go about solving this specific issue?

In addition, what are some general tips for debugging latex errors in doxygen? Are there any log files somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use both Doxygen and LaTeX. When compiling formulas, Doxygen will take the contents of your LaTeX equations, copies the ones that haven't been generated to `html/_formulas.tex` (relative to the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` specified in the Doxyfile), attempt to compile the `tex` file, and then copies the result to png files.

If you use `\f$ a+b \f$`, the formula will appear inline; and if you use `\f[ a+b \f]` the formula will be in "display" style.

It sounds like one of your formulas has an error. If, while the command line is displaying the error, you edit the _formulas.tex file, you can probably track down the error. A "missing $" error probably means you forgot to close a set of braces somewhere.

Comment: This solved my problem. For completeness sake, I found the `_formulas.tex` file to be in the `doxygen/html` directory. I expected it to be in the directory from which I ran doxygen, which is what puzzled me. Please edit this into your answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In latex, the $ symbol opens math mode, which usually means you're typesetting some sort of equation. If you have equations, surround them with $, e.g. $\frac{1}{2}$

i would assume that doxygen is just passing the .tex file to the command line, in which case there should be a latex log file with specific line numbers where errors occurred. The .log, .aux, etc. are in the same directory as your .tex file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In doxygen, `@f$`, or `\f$` play the role of switching to latex math mode.

My problem is exactly understanding what doxygen does. The latex source is embedded within source code comments so I do not directly write a .tex file.

I could find no .tex or .log files...