# How do I find the location of a Doxygen latex error?

Tags: latex, doxygen

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170406/tips-for-debugging-latex-errors-in-doxygen).

Doxygen is outputing a warning while trying to generate docs for HTML:

> warning: reached end of file while inside a f$ block!
>   The command that should end the block seems to be missing!

I understand what this means, but I have *lots* of LaTeX in this particular document. Unfortunately, the line number of the error is just the last line in the file, and Doxygen doesn't output the the `\f$` that opened the math mode.

Is there a way to get Doxygen to output this, rather than me having to scour the file for a missing or malformed `\f$`? Something that might produce more verbose errors?

---

Before I finished typing this question, I found the offending line by browsing the generated HTML and looking for a function in that file that didn't get documented. That at least gave me enough of a hint for where to start looking. Still it would be great if there was a more concrete answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

When generating for Latex with Doxygen, it is indeed not obvious to spot errors. One solution is to get down into the `latex` generated folder, and try these steps:

1. Run generated makefile (`$ make`), and look for pdflatex compiler output,
2. If it fails, load the file `refman.tex` into some Latex IDE (say, Texstudio or equivalent) and try to compile from there.
3. If still unable to locate error, you can run manually pdflatex with option halt-on-error:
   (`$ pdflatex -halt-on-error refman.tex`). This way, it will stop immediately at the error location.